# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, but file does exist

Tags: python, io, cgi

I keep getting an IO Error stating my directory doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

I have this in a separate file named **pirate.py**:

```
with open("/images/image.jpg", "rb") as fin:
    image_data = fin.read()

with open("pirate.py","wb") as fout:
    fout.write("image_data="+repr(image_data))
```

And then the code in my main file

```
from pirate import image_data

# Content-type declaration
print('Content-type: text/html\n')

def main():
    print('<!doctype html><head><meta charset="utf-8">')
    print('<style>html {background:url (data:image/gif;base64,' + pirate.image_data + ')
```

I'm trying to encode an image in base64 and then use it as a background in a .cgi, I'm sure the rest of my code is working, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Will you please provide full traceaback?

Comment: You are probably not in the correct directory when you run it.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of how your directories are structured? Where is pirate.py in relation to where you're executing the main script?

Comment: Full traceback = IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'server.csmcis.net/~ahatfiel/images/tinyPirate.jpg'

Comment: pirate.py and main script are both in /cgi-bin/

Comment: @coollife where is `cgi-bin` in relation to `'server.csmcis.net/~ahatfiel/images/tinyPirate.jpg`?

Comment: cgi-bin and images are both under server.csmcis.net/~ahatfiel/

Comment: @coollife Then you can just use `open("../images/tinyPirate.jpg")`. Also, if `server.csmcis.net` is at the top level of the filesystem, you need to use a leading `/`: `/server.csmcis.net/~ahatfiel/images/tinyPirate.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use absolute file paths. or use root prefix ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**))

Comment: I used a full path in my code, but I edited it out to images/image.jpg on here. I will try the other solution though.

Comment: Maybe this is permission problem?

Answer (score 0):

repr is not what you want, you are saying the image data is base64 ... so make it base 64

```
with open("pirate.py","wb") as fout:
  fout.write("image_data="+base64.b64encode(image_data))
```

then in addition you say

```
from pirate import image_data
```

then you reference it as

```
pirate.image_data
```

when you should just reference it as

```
image_data
```

theres probably some other probelems since the image image path you show is not the image path from your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your code says

```
open("/images/image.jpg", "rb")
```

I suspect the "/" at the beginning is the problem. Or is your images folder in your root?